# Jquery Datepicker working fine underbody tag but not working under <td> tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp, datepicker, jquery-ui-datepicker

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#datepicker").datepicker();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td width="150"> Abend Date(Cycle):<input id="datepicker" /></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Datepicker is part of jquery UI, not jquery. Not sure why it worked for you, but in your snippet it doesn't work even when moved outside of the `<td>` tag.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#datepicker").datepicker();
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<table>
  <tr>
    <td width="150"> Abend Date(Cycle): <input id="datepicker" /></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```